# Bower is not updating in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6

Tags: bower, visual-studio-2015

I have just installed React using Bower inside Visual Studio 2015 CTP6.
In Dependencies -> Bower -> React (0.13.0)
I do have React package.(js files are also in bower_components/react folder on disk)

When I try to add script  `<script src="~/lib/` I do not have React in my list of scripts.

Intelligence not working and JavaScript is not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this sample I added a simple rule to copy all the .js files:

```
{
    "name": "WebApplication",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "3.0.0",
        "jquery": "1.10.2",
        "jquery-validation": "1.11.1",
        "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.2",
        "hammer.js": "2.0.4",
        "bootstrap-touch-carousel": "0.8.0",
        "react": "~0.13.1"
    },
    "exportsOverride": {
        "bootstrap": {
            "js": "dist/js/*.*",
            "css": "dist/css/*.*",
            "fonts": "dist/fonts/*.*"
        },
        "bootstrap-touch-carousel": {
            "js": "dist/js/*.*",
            "css": "dist/css/*.*"
        },
        "hammer": {
            "": "hammer.{js,min.js}"
        },
        "react": {
            "":  "*.js"
        }

    }
}
```

the result is that when you run install bower task you'll find inside the wwwroot/lib a directory named react with just the ,js files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have configure the exportsOverride section in the bower.json

Comment: Can you give me the example? Thanks